# overflow on div with width in percentage doesnt work

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

If i give a div absolute width, then overflow works fine but if i give width in percentage, overflow is not properly applied and pushes the element next to it out of screen.
JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/mt9nrxxd/

```
<div id="contentContainer">
<div id="firstLevel">
<div id="firstChild">
<div id="excessWidth">
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="secondChild">
</div>
</div>

#contentContainer{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background: white;
}
#firstLevel{
    width: 100%
}
#firstChild{
    width:100%;
    height: 50px;
    overflow:auto;
    background: yellow;
}
#excessWidth{
   background: red;
   width:550px;
   height: 50px;
}
#secondChild{
   background: orange;
   height: 50px;
   min-width: 80px;
}
```

Comment: What div causes the problem?

Comment: You'll need to clarify. The only element you have with any sort of overflow is `firstChild`, which has 100% width. Because all of its parents are 100% width, it just means that `firstChild` will span the entire width of the page. Being that its content (`excessWidth`) is only 550px wide, it doesn't need to overflow at all.

Comment: If you try to reduce excesswidth width, it won't occupy full screen because of display flex. But the moment excessWidth width start becoming more than 100% - 80px, it starts pushing secondChild instead of normal scrolling action.